# browsing internal ldap of wso2 identity server

Tags: ldap, wso2

I'm trying to browse the embedded ldap server of WSO2 Identity Server thanks to a LDAP client.
I didn't change the default configuration and I connected successfully as uid=admin,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org.
But then, I don't see the other users I created thanks to WSO2 IS console.

Where and how can I see how the users are stored in the embedded ldap server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default configuration, WSO2 Identity Server get connected to the embedded LDAP server using the user uid=admin,ou=system. And, users will be created in ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org and groups will be created in ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org.

Did you create the user uid=admin,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org ?

Comment: The admin user is created. I'm able to connect with his credentials.
I also created another admin user thanks to the UI, and I'm also able to connect the ldap client to the embedded ldap server as this new user.
But, once I'm connected, I don't manage to browse the directories. I t may come from my client configuration (Apache Directory Studio).

Comment: try the user uid=admin,ou=system to browse the ldap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ldapsearch` command line tool or an [LDAP browser](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

#### see also

- [Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)

Comment: I use apache ds ldap browser. 
I'm able to connect the server but I don't see my users anywhere.